# Duplicate data entry in table

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

How can I prevent a duplication data in table when I click the save button. I am using this code but it is not working. I am using dynamic input fields when the user click the add more button it will add a field.

here is my form

```
<form name="add_name" id="add_name">
    <input type="text" name="fld_idnum[]" placeholder="Enter your ID Number" class="form-control name_list" />
    <input type="text" name="fld_name[]" placeholder="Enter your Lastname Firstname Middle Initial" class="form-control name_list"
    />
    <input type="text" name="cell_num[]" placeholder="Enter cellphone No. of your Parents/Guardians" class="form-control name_list"
    />
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button>

    <button name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>&nbsp; Save </button>
</form>
```

this is my script

```
    <script>  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"addstudentaccount.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

this is my addstudentaccount.php code

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");  

$number = count($_POST["fld_idnum"]); 
$number = count($_POST["fld_name"]); 
$number = count($_POST["cell_num"]); 

if($number > 0)  
{  
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
    {  
        if(trim($_POST["fld_idnum"][$i]) >= 1) {
            echo "Already Exists!";
        }

        if(trim($_POST["fld_idnum"][$i] != '' && $_POST["fld_name"][$i] != ''))  
        {  
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tblstudaccount(fld_idnum, fld_name, cell_num) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["fld_idnum"][$i])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["fld_name"][$i])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["cell_num"][$i])."')";  
            mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  

            echo "Students Inserted Successfully"; 
        }
        else  
        {  
            echo "Please Input All Fields";  
            exit();
        }
    }     
}           
?>
```

Comment: You're using the same `$number` variable for all the counts.

Comment: Create a unique index in the table. If you try to insert a duplicate it will get an error.

Comment: And stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, use prepared statements and `bind_param()`.

Comment: how can I create a unique index. Please help me.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can always restrict wrong data by put constrains on database.

> login to  phpmyadmin and give unique key to field which you want unique

[image]
please refer attachment

Comment: <?php


 define (DB_USER, "root");
 define (DB_PASSWORD, "");
 define (DB_DATABASE, "test");
 define (DB_HOST, "localhost");
 $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);


 if(!empty($_POST["name"])){


  foreach ($_POST["name"] as $key => $value) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tagslist(name) VALUES ('".$value."')";
   $mysqli->query($sql);
  }
  echo json_encode(['success'=>'Names Inserted successfully.']);  
 }


?>